# Merge data of two duplicate rows in excel

Tags: excel, merge, duplicates

So I have a huge data set in excel (almost 6000 rows), where I have certain duplicate rows(not all), such as below:

```
Batman      1801.7  214.13  1587.57 
Batman      1985.8  204.69  1781.11
```

I have to merge these cells as one, like the one below:

```
Batman      3787.5  418.82  3368.68
```

So the data columns are the sum of the two rows.

Cheers
SB

Answer (score 0):

You can use a simple pivot to get sum of values for each character in col 1.